# python google query returning only a single result

Tags: python, google-search

This code, according to "geeksforgeeks" should return 10 results however for me it is only returning one. Any thoughts?

```
try: 
    from googlesearch import search 
except ImportError: 
    print("No module named 'google' found") 

query = "dogs"

for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2): 
    print(j)
```

Comment: What does `stop=1` mean?

Comment: @mkrieger1 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/performing-google-search-using-python-code/

Comment: Did you try changing it to something like `stop=5`?

Comment: that's done the trick @mkrieger1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using this library:

https://github.com/MarioVilas/googlesearch

According to its [documentation](https://python-googlesearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you are misunderstanding what the function arguments mean.

- num (int) – Number of results *per page*
- stop (int) – Last result to retrieve. Use None to keep searching forever.

By using `stop=1` you only get one result. Change it to something higher.